# Converting String value to Decimal

Tags: string, decimal

So I'm trying to convert Ethereum Wei to Eth. The described method of doing this is to divide by 10^18. However my attempt to do this is not producing the right values.

```
private static Decimal toEth(String wei) {
    System.debug(wei);
    Decimal ethAmount = Decimal.valueOf(wei).divide(10^18, 2, System.RoundingMode.UP);
    System.debug(ethAmount);
    return ethAmount;
}
```

I was hoping that someone might know off the top of their head why this isn't working.

```
17:24:02.30 (340307342)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|1000000000000000000
17:24:02.30 (340773708)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|41666666666666666.67
17:24:02.30 (340859619)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|50000000000
17:24:02.30 (340918639)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|2083333333.34
17:24:02.30 (341742530)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|998866000000000000
17:24:02.30 (341821603)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|41619416666666666.67
17:24:02.30 (341852276)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|54000000000
17:24:02.30 (341895487)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|2250000000.00
17:24:02.30 (342353811)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|400001000000000000000000
17:24:02.30 (342540215)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|16666708333333333333333.34
17:24:02.30 (342613123)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|54000000000
17:24:02.30 (342682201)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|2250000000.00
17:24:02.30 (343232044)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|1000000000000000
17:24:02.30 (343293233)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|41666666666666.67
17:24:02.30 (343323784)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|31824000000
17:24:02.30 (343365219)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|1326000000.00
17:24:02.30 (343715745)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|1999000000000000000
17:24:02.30 (343772847)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|83291666666666666.67
17:24:02.30 (343801964)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|45000000000
17:24:02.30 (343841403)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|1875000000.00
```

Comment: (to post preformatted text, wrap in triple backticks: ```)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is not an exponentiation operator in Apex. It is [bitwise XOR](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

`10^18` actually evaluates to `24`, which makes sense of your division results.

To perform exponentiation, use [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_math.htm), e.g.

```
Math.pow(10, 18)
```